# Simulate a click on a Button, normal methods don't work

Tags: javascript, angular, events, click, simulate

I try to simulate a click on a Button with JavaScript.

I have this tried with those commands:

```js
$('#loginbutton').click();
$('#loginbutton').trigger("click");
$('#loginbutton').on("click");
document.getElementById('loginbutton').click();
document.elementFromPoint(658,697).click();
document.getElementsByName("loginButton")[0].click();
document.getElementsByClassName("login-button")[0].click();
$('.login-button').on("click");
$('button')[9].click();
$('[id="loginbutton"]').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="ba-btn ba-btn-primary ba-btn-icon login-button" name="loginButton" type="button" role="button" id="loginbutton" _ngcontent-fjt-c65="">Anmelden</button>
```

but nothing works.
The web site contains that:

```
/<app-root class="init"/>/</app-root/>
```

I think that is Code written with the Angular Framework
Is this the problem? I do not own the web site.

Comment: How do you know it is not working? What is the source-code of the button, and what would you expect to happen upon click?

Comment: Impossible to debug without a [mre], and since you don't own the web site, and it sounds like you're trying to automate a login process (which is on the edge of legality), I doubt we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

- There is actually something to click on
- The "button" in the HTML is before the JavaScript

```js
$('#loginbutton').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="loginbutton" onclick="console.log('You made a click')">Click</button>
```

Comment: The OP already has that in their list of things they attempted...